# Actions on Google Submission For Review Fails

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to submit my **Actions** to Google for Review and eventually **Release**. I tried the beta release process and I keep getting the error as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Intent 'actions.intent.CALL' is using the reserved namespace. Please choose a name that does not start with 'actions'.]

I tried to remove any mention of the word `CALL` in my code (Intents, Actions, Parameters, Training phrases, events, etc.) to see if that would fix the problem. But it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't you use of "CALL", it is the "actions.intent" portion. Those are reserved for the built-in Intents that are, or may be, available.

Unless you're using one of these Intents - your name should be something else.

Comment: Hi there @Prisoner. None of my intents have the 'actions.intent' portion in their name. But I do remember a last version of my cloud function where I tried to use `actions.intent.CALL`  but it didn't work as expected. So I deleted that action from my cloud function.   

I even renamed my Cloud function name to see if it was a caching issue, no luck. The error is still there. The only place in my code where `actions` is referenced is `app.middleware((conv) => {
     conv.hasScreen = conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT');

});`. I don't think that is the problem

Comment: It would be nice if the error could pinpoint me to the specific intent that is throwing this error.

Comment: None of the Intents you named in Dialogflow have this name?

Comment: None. I only define `actions_intent_PERMISSION` and `actions_intent_option` as events in Dialogflow, and not as intents. I give specific names to my intents and I map them with my cloud functions in `NodeJS`. But there is no reference at all of `actions.` or `actions_` in my NodeJS code.